# Access old laptop HDD from PC

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, windows-xp, data-recovery, sata

Background;

Laptop HDD was designated C, is at least 10 years old and runs XP (I believe), password protected at login (not boot)

My computer is very new, runs windows 10

I am attempting to recover image files from it

Things I've tried so far;

Plugged Laptop HDD in via SATA to mobo. The HDD isn't detected immediately. Have tried to initialise via admin tools but get "the system cannot find the file specified" error message.

Have used various data recovery tools - Ease US found some data on there but not much. Biggest was a 384mb .wim file. (I am assuming .wim won't contain any actual documents, seems to just be OS data)

So the drive is working, just can't get into it. Could I try to boot from it? Not sure that would work without it being initialised first..

SMART status via crystal disk https://i.stack.imgur.com/Am4rc.png

Any help very appreciated!

Comment: I have no solution for you, but if you think that the drive's platter surface may be defective due to old age, you should attempt to run SpinRite on it. That has helped me to get a "damaged" disc running again, with only very few unrecoverable files.

Comment: Thanks Dan, HDD is spinning and sounds normal. I can access some info from it, just not all.

Comment: Can't access some files, or some partitions? From your description it looks like it can recognize the filesystem and find some files on it. Sounds like a good candidate for SprinRite first, if then files don't show up try a recovery tool which will then work on the "corrected" drive. If that doesn't work then you're out of luck (but don't trash the drive then)

Comment: SpinRite is like an autistic disc-checker which looks at every single byte as many times as reasonable in order to try to guess if it is correct. Usually this is fast, but if bytes are found to be troublesome, it will work on those for a long time to attempt to recover them.

Comment: There's only one partition. spinrite seems to fix a broken HDD. This HDD is not broken..https://rtechsupport.org/kb/datarecovery/ I'm currently downloading linux so I can clone the HDD from there. I've decided the SMART check failed as there was incomplete information + health status is "unknown"

Comment: A recovery tool, on the other hand, doesn't look at bad bytes this way, it scans the unused area for data which may be a file, and if it could be a file, it creates a reference in the HDD's "filetable" so that the OS can access it again. If the file is read correctly, it ends up as a normally recovered file, else it is put into some lost and found folder so you can look at the contents of it manually and eventually fix it manually. SpinRite doesn't know and won't care about files, it cares about bytes .

Comment: It may be broken, for example if a magnet was close to the drive. Or if some neutrinos happened to hit some bits. Physical damage as in anything that might change the magnetic properties of the drive and thus modify bytes. SpinrRite works with statistics in order to check a byte.

Comment: @DanielF “scans the unused area [...] else it is put into some lost and found folder” It looks like you are describing a strange mashup of a file carver, an undeleter and a file system tree reconstruction. Can you name any tool that does such a confusing mix of things?

Comment: I had something like this in mind https://www.piriform.com/recuva please correct me if I'm wrong.